# Alternate to assigning return values

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C. On one of the developers documentation, I found the following statemenet.

**The following statement invokes the lockFocusIfCanDraw method and assigns the return value to
flag. It does not generate a compiler warning unless there is a mismatch between the type for flag
and the method’s return type. Nonetheless, this pattern is strongly discouraged.**

```
flag = aView.lockFocusIfCanDraw;
```

In addition to the one above, I can think of many situations of this kind. For instance I might want to capture the display text from a box and assign it to a local string etc.

I am just wondering, if the above statement is discouraged, what is the recommended way of handling such situation?

Comment: For the record, the statement is from The Objective-C Programming Language -> Objects, Classes, and Messaging -> Object Messaging -> [Dot Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17) -> Incorrect Use of Dot Syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dot syntax for calling methods should only be used for properties (i.e. when calling accessors). Since `lockFocusIfCanDraw` is not an accessor method, you should use the regular square brackets syntax, i.e. `flag = [aView lockFocusIfCanDraw];` instead.

Comment: And how could I know if lockFocusIfCanDraw is a property or a method?

Answer (score 2):

flag = [aView lockFocusIfCanDraw];